# Stored Procedure: Values in the three columns are same even though the Order Date is different

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a Stored Procedure Problem listed here::

For example Customer A has: 
        i.) Five orders in first 30 days,
        ii.) Five orders in first 60 days,
       iii.) Five orders in first 90 days

So the result should be:

```
     A.) First 30 Days: Five orders
     B.) First 60 Days: Five + Five = 10 Orders
     C.) First 90 Days: Five + Five + Five = 15 Orders
```

However, my stored procedure is showing '15 Orders' for all 30,60 and 90 days. Could you please help me, so that my Stored Procedure shows '5 orders' in 30 days, '10 orders in 60 days' and '15 orders' in 90 days. [BELOW IS THE PART OF THE CODE]
Thank You for your Help.

---

```
 IF (@CUSTOMERID IS NOT NULL)
 BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #TEMP_D
(
CUSTOMERID VARCHAR(20),
ORDERID INT,
PRODUCTID INT,
QUANTITY VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO #TEMP_F(CUSTOMERID,ORDERID,PRODUCTID,QUANTITY)
 (CUSTOMERID VARCHAR(20),ORDERID INT,PRODUCTID INT,QUANTITY VARCHAR(20))
 INSERT INTO #TEMP_D(CUSTOMERID,ORDERID,PRODUCTID,QUANTITY)
 SELECT C.CUSTOMERID, COUNT(O.ORDERID),COUNT(OD.PRODUCTID),
        RANKING = CASE
        WHEN SUM(OD.QUANTITY*OD.UNITPRICE)>250 THEN 'REGULAR'
        WHEN SUM(OD.QUANTITY*OD.UNITPRICE)< 250 THEN 'MODERATE'
        END
        FROM CUSTOMERS C 
        INNER JOIN
        ORDERS O ON C.CUSTOMERID=O.CUSTOMERID
        INNER JOIN
        [ORDER DETAILS] OD ON O.ORDERID=OD.ORDERID
        WHERE (C.CUSTOMERID = @CUSTOMERID)
        GROUP BY C.CUSTOMERID



CREATE TABLE #TEMP_E
(
CUSTOMERID VARCHAR(20),
ORDERID INT,
PRODUCTID INT,
QUANTITY VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO #TEMP_F(CUSTOMERID,ORDERID,PRODUCTID,QUANTITY)
 (CUSTOMERID VARCHAR(20),ORDERID INT,PRODUCTID INT,QUANTITY VARCHAR(20))
 INSERT INTO #TEMP_D(CUSTOMERID,ORDERID,PRODUCTID,QUANTITY)
 SELECT C.CUSTOMERID, COUNT(O.ORDERID),COUNT(OD.PRODUCTID),
        RANKING = CASE
        WHEN SUM(OD.QUANTITY*OD.UNITPRICE)>250 THEN 'REGULAR'
        WHEN SUM(OD.QUANTITY*OD.UNITPRICE)< 250 THEN 'MODERATE'
        END
        FROM CUSTOMERS C 
        INNER JOIN
        ORDERS O ON C.CUSTOMERID=O.CUSTOMERID
        INNER JOIN
        [ORDER DETAILS] OD ON O.ORDERID=OD.ORDERID
        WHERE (C.CUSTOMERID = @CUSTOMERID)
        GROUP BY C.CUSTOMERID


CREATE TABLE #TEMP_F
(
CUSTOMERID VARCHAR(20),
ORDERID INT,
PRODUCTID INT,
QUANTITY VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO #TEMP_F(CUSTOMERID,ORDERID,PRODUCTID,QUANTITY)
 (CUSTOMERID VARCHAR(20),ORDERID INT,PRODUCTID INT,QUANTITY VARCHAR(20))
 INSERT INTO #TEMP_D(CUSTOMERID,ORDERID,PRODUCTID,QUANTITY)
 SELECT C.CUSTOMERID, COUNT(O.ORDERID),COUNT(OD.PRODUCTID),
        RANKING = CASE
        WHEN SUM(OD.QUANTITY*OD.UNITPRICE)>250 THEN 'REGULAR'
        WHEN SUM(OD.QUANTITY*OD.UNITPRICE)< 250 THEN 'MODERATE'
        END
        FROM CUSTOMERS C 
        INNER JOIN
        ORDERS O ON C.CUSTOMERID=O.CUSTOMERID
        INNER JOIN
        [ORDER DETAILS] OD ON O.ORDERID=OD.ORDERID
        WHERE (C.CUSTOMERID = @CUSTOMERID)
        GROUP BY C.CUSTOMERID


SELECT D.CUSTOMERID, D.ORDERID AS 'ORDERS 30 DAYD',D.PRODUCTID AS 'PRODUCTS 30 DAYS',D.QUANTITY, E.CUSTOMERID, E.ORDERID AS 'ORDERS 60                 
   DAYS',E.PRODUCTID AS 'PRODUCTS 60 DAYS',E.QUANTITY,  F.CUSTOMERID, F.ORDERID AS 'ORDERS 90 DAYD',F.PRODUCTID AS 'PRODUCTS 90 DAYS',F.QUANTITY
   FROM #TEMP_D D
   INNER JOIN  #TEMP_E E  ON D.CUSTOMERID=E.CUSTOMERID
   INNER JOIN #TEMP_F F ON E.CUSTOMERID = F.CUSTOMERID
```

END

Comment: Would you mind posting some code and possible information about the table structure?

Comment: I posted part of the Code Above. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something here, but your 3 queries into temporary tables all seem to be the same query.   You are not filtering by date in your WHERE clauses, therefore they will all come up with the same result (15 orders).